# Get year of datetime where date is not fully specified with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, jdbc

I have a Java program connected to a MySQL database with JDBC in which I introduce datetimes. Many times only the year is introduced by assigning `00` to the days and months not specified, for instance `1700-00-00` for the year 1700.

When I try to get the date from a ResultSet using `ResultSet.getDate().toString()` I get the  proper date from the fully specified dates but in the case of partial dates I get: previous_year-11-30, so `1699-11-30` for the year 1700. When I try with `ResultSet.getDate().getTime()` I get the equivalent result: `-8520339600000`. `ResultSet.getTimestamp()` gives the same results.

Conversely, when I look for the datetime with MySQL I get the proper value `1700-00-00`.

I have tried with different years obtaining the same results. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is how I fetch the data (this is one method, many other are similar and give same results):

```
public naixement(int fill) throws DBException{
        super();
        try {
            String str = "select * from naixement where id_fill=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(str);
            pst.setInt(1, fill);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()){
                this.idFill = fill;
                this.idLloc = nullify(rs.getInt("id_lloc"));
                this.idUnio = nullify(rs.getInt("id_unio"));
                try {
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Data de naixement: "+rs.getString("data_naixement")+
                                " id: "+fill);
                    }catch (NullPointerException e){}
                    this.dataNaixement = new date(rs.getString("data_naixement"));
                } catch (dateException ex) {
                    this.dataNaixement = new date();
                }
            }else{
                throw new DBException("S'ha intentat aconseguir un naixement "
                    + "inexistent (id de la persona: "+fill+")");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Excepció amb id_fill: "+fill);
            Logger.getLogger(municipi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue.

Comment: Exactly what [data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) is the `data_naixement` column in the table?

Comment: I appologise if I was not clear enough about that. It's a `datetime` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getDate` method that you are using is implemented by your JDBC jar provided by vendor(In your case MySQL). I believe these methods internally uses DateFromat to convert dates from database to java.util.Date that causes problem. In Mysql jan is represented as 1 and december as 12 month of the year So a datefromat is used that converts it to Date by considering year range 1-12.java.util.Date doesn't work same way, It consider 0 as Jan and 11 as December and DateFormat and Date are implemented in a Way that they can go to next month or date if given date or month is greater than given range.

For Example. If given month is 13 then date will go to Jan of next year.
01-13-1700 will go to 01-Jan-1701.

```
 DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
    Date d=dateFormat.parse("1700-00-00");
    System.out.println(d);
    d=dateFormat.parse("1700-01-01");        
    System.out.println(d);
    d=dateFormat.parse("1700-13-01");        
    System.out.println(d);
```

Execute this code and you will get a better understanding
**Output:-**

```
Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 IST 1699
Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1700
Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1701
```

Problem is you have some old values in DB that are causing problem. So you  need to modify them or add some custom logic to fetch dates as String and then convert it to Date.

Comment: Thanks to you now I understand the problem. However, when I try to get the dates as String I get the same results: `1699-11-30 00:00:00.0`. I can't find a solution which doesn't get rid of `-00-00` and gives a proper value when readed from ResultSet.

Comment: a `ResultSet.getCharacterStream` approach has solved my problem. Thank you to let me understand the problem.